# Select values from a list with constraints

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am currently stuck at this problem:

Let's say, I have a list of tuples, `l`:

```
l = [(0, 2), (4, 7), (3, 7), (0, 7), (10, 11), (9, 11), (8, 11), (0, 11), (0, 11)]
```

I want to select only the tuples that has the lowest difference between it's first and second element while keeping the start or end index fixed.

So, for eg, if we set the start_index as 0: then we have `(0, 2)`, `(0, 7)`, `(0, 11)`, and `(0, 11)`.
Since, `(0, 2)` has the lowest difference between it's elements, we select that.

Similarly, if we set the end_index as 7: then we have `(4, 7)`, `(3, 7)`, `(0, 7)`. Since, `(4, 7)` has the lowest difference between it's elements, we select that.

Finally, the output I am looking for is:

```
out = [(0, 2), (4, 7), (10, 11)]
```

Edit:

I tried the following:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def same_start_index(spans, N):
    l = []
    for (i, j) in spans:
        if i == N:
           l.append((i, j))
    return l

def same_end_index(spans, N):
    l = []
    for (i, j) in spans:
        if j == N:
           l.append((i, j))
    return l


start_d = defaultdict(list)
for n in range(len(sentence)):
    for item in same_start_index(l, n):
        start_d[n].append(item)

end_d = defaultdict(list)
for n in range(len(sentence)):
    for item in same_end_index(l, n):
        end_d[n].append(item)


print(start_d)
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {0: [(0, 2), (0, 7), (0, 11), (0, 11)], 3: [(3, 7)], 4: [(4, 7)], 8: [(8, 11)], 9: [(9, 11)], 10: [(10, 11)]})

print(end_d)
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {2: [(0, 2)], 7: [(4, 7), (3, 7), (0, 7)], 11: [(10, 11), (9, 11), (8, 11), (0, 11), (0, 11)]})
```

Comment: Do the `start_index` and `end_index` are given by ourselves?

Comment: let's assume the lower and upper bounds are fixed.

Comment: @martineau: can you please undo your downvote now?

Comment: It's unclear how did you get the final sample output `[(0, 2), (4, 7), (10, 11)]` . i.e. if you set first element to be 0 or the second to be 7, why the other 2. Even if assume you choose 0 or 7 (that will give (0, 2) and (4, 7), but why also (10, 11)? What if there are multiple tuples with same difference? is it always the case that second element is greater than the first?

Comment: I agree with @buran that the question's unclear. Why are there only three tuples in the final output list? What about those with starting values of 3, 8, 9, and 10? In other words, why isn't there something for every possible starting value? I'm downvoting again for a different reason.

Answer (score 0):

So this is my solution to the problem. Bit unsure if this is what you are looking for.

```
out = []
def same_start_index(list_, N):
    lowest_diff_tuple = (0,0)
    lowest_diff = 10

    for (i,j) in list_:
        if i == N:
            diff = j-i
            if diff < lowest_diff:
                lowest_diff = diff
                lowest_diff_tuple = (i,j)
    out.append(lowest_diff_tuple)

def same_end_index(list_, N):
    lowest_diff_tuple = (0,0)
    lowest_diff = 10


    for (i,j) in list_:
        if j == N:
            diff = j-i
            if diff < lowest_diff:
                lowest_diff = diff
                lowest_diff_tuple = (i,j)
    out.append(lowest_diff_tuple)
    
same_start_index(l, 0)
same_end_index(l, 7)
same_start_index(l, 10)

print(out)
```

I hope you find this solution helpful